# Android-Webrtc: Getting Assertion error in copyI420Buffer() of AndroidVideoDecoder

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

In few devices(like Motorola Moto E4 Plus, Realme 6i, Lenovo K8 Plus), I am getting Assertion error in copyI420Buffer() of AndroidVideoDecoder.java.

In Crashlytics, I found the below logs:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: Stride is not divisible by two: 1229
   at org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder.copyI420Buffer(AndroidVideoDecoder.java:523)
   at org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder.deliverByteFrame(AndroidVideoDecoder.java:498)
   at org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder.deliverDecodedFrame(AndroidVideoDecoder.java:413)
   at org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$1.run(AndroidVideoDecoder.java:373)
```

Any help or guidance to resolve this issue will be well appreciated.

Comment: There's a relevant sounding check here (https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/android/src/java/org/webrtc/AndroidVideoDecoder.java#480); you could try and update the version of the webrtc SDK you are using if developing an app.